# How to get all image sizes available for a site using add_image_size?

Tags: wordpress

I need to get all image sizes available for a site using themes or plugins set using the WordPress function `add_image_size()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/.

Could somebody point me to a code that could help me get the sizes for different sites ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all possible thumbnail/image size from the global wordpress variable `$_wp_additional_image_sizes`

Simply do this where you need it:

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;    
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $_wp_additional_image_sizes );
echo '</pre>';
```